# Java JAX_RS REST Server for internal application use

Tags: java, maven, server, jax-rs

I am currently working on a little project of mine, trying out Maven and a few things I learnt recently.

Project Structure

```
 +- myProject 
       +- pom.xml  ... <packaging>pom, aggregator (<modules>) of frontend & backend
       |
       +- frontend
       |  +- pom.xml  ... <parent>myProject, <packaging>pom, aggregator (<modules>) of window & ***
       |  |  
       |  +- window
       |  |  +- pom.xml  ... <parent>frontend
       |  |
       |  +- ***
       |     +- pom.xml  ... <parent>frontend
       |
       +- backend
          +- pom.xml  ... <parent>myProject, <packaging>pom, aggregator (<modules>) of database & ***
          |
          +- core
          |  +- pom.xml  ... <parent>backend
          |
          +- ***
             +- pom.xml  ... <parent>backend
```

I have it purposefully separated into a `Frontend` and a `Backend` project, which respectively contain some projects which I need to get my Application running. For the Projects in `Backend` I wanted to create a Rest API that the projects in `Frontend` can call using JAX-RS(javax.ws.rs), because I have worked with it before.

My Problem with this is, that as far as I know, I need a server running, which listens for the HTTP calls to invoke my API, but I have no Idea how to set that up, what to search for or where to even start.

I basically want something that works more or less like this:

Call a method from the `Backend` Project somewhere in the `Frontend` project

```
startServer();
```

which starts some kind of Server in the background which then listens for my REST HTTP calls, (So it should contain my APIs from the Projects in `Backend`)

And then when I close out of the Application I want to call

```
stopServer();
```

to end it.

Is there something like that out there, that I could use as a background Server? Or is there possibly a way where I don't need one?

If anyone has an idea I would gladly hear it. You don't have to explain everything, it would suffice to just point me to something I can use, but I will gladly take every guidance you are willing to give.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: #1 Are you open to an advice related to an architecture  more current and requested in the enterprises?  #2 Did you ear about spring-boot ?

Comment: Spring Boot is a good alternative, Quarkus another. You could also run your code in an application server (there are free ones and many work from your IDE). Think about how you will run this in production and try to get the development environment as similar as possible.

Comment: Ah thank you, Spring Boot seems like it would fit my purpose very well. And I will keep that in mind @ewarmner , thank you^^